# modify a property of an object in the functional way

Tags: javascript, dictionary, functional-programming, immutability

In javascript programming in the functional way is a great benefit. I'm trying to modify a property of an object contained in an array of objects in the functional way that means that the item that is the object passed in the `map` function cannot be modified. If I do something like this:

```
const modObjects = objects.map((item) => {

   item.foo = "foo" + 3;

   return item;
});
```

this is not functional because item is modified inside the function. do you know any other approach to this problem?

Comment: you are mutating the original object. map is the wrong method.

Comment: Make a copy of the `item`, change the property, return the copy.

Answer (score 5):

A new (ES6) way that is *really* immutable and in the spirit of functional programming:

```js
// A. Map function that sets obj[prop] to a fixed value
const propSet = prop => value => obj => ({...obj, [prop]: value})

// B. Map function that modifies obj.foo2 only if it exists
const foo2Modify = obj =>
    obj.hasOwnProperty('foo2') ? {...obj, foo2: 'foo ' + obj.foo2} : obj

// Usage examples of A and B
const initialData = [{'foo': 'one'}, {'foo2': 'two'}, {'foo3': 'three'}]
const newData1 = initialData.map(propSet('foo2')('bar')) // Set value
const newData2 = initialData.map(foo2Modify) // Use a modify function 
console.log(initialData) // Initial data should not change
console.log(newData1) // Each object should contain the new fixed foo2
console.log(newData2) // Modify foo2 only if it exists in initial data
```

Comment: Where can I find documentation for the syntax in the first line: `{...obj, [prop]: value}`? I'm confused by the square brackets.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Object.assign` to create a copy of the item obj and return that from the map callback.

> [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
>
> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

Here is an example

```js
let data = [
  {"foo": "one"},
  {"foo": "two"},
  {"foo": "three"}
]

let newData = data.map( item => {
  let itemCopy = Object.assign({}, item);
  itemCopy.foo = "foo " + item.foo;
  return itemCopy;
})

console.log(data)
console.log(newData)
```

Comment: If there are references in `data` to mutable objects, referential transparency will be broken for `newData`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this:

```
const modObjects = objects.map((item) => {

   return { ...objects, foo: "foo" + 3; };

});
```

The reason that this: `objects.map((item) => { ...destSchema, foo: "foo" + 3; });` doesn't work is that they made it this way to make the JS interpreter understand whether it is a scope or an object. You MUST use `return`

Comment: or you can add parens `(...)` around braces `{}`. so there is at least one alternative.

Answer (score 1):

In modern JavaScript you can use spread operator on object inside of an object literal for this:

```js
const modObjects = objects.map(
  item => ({...item, foo: item.foo + 3})
)
```

Notice parentheses `()` around object literal. They are needed to disambiguate object literal `{}` from code block `{}` in lambdas. Another way is to use code block with `return`:

```js
const modObjects = objects.map(
  item => { return {...item, foo: item.foo + 3} }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have extended @Dimitrios Tsalkakis answer to change property with a callback function.

Example: https://repl.it/@robie2011/ts-set-property-functional

Typescript:

```js
function mapProperty<T>(prop: string){
    return (cb: (propValue: any) => any) => (obj: any) => ({...obj, [prop]: cb(obj[prop])}) as (T)
}
```